# Backgroundworker stops twice

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a problem with background worker.
I don't know how exactly to describe it.
Actually its a game and with the background worker ever x milisecs i update the progress bar and check  if anyone has lost/won or the time is up.
If someome has win the game ends.
If both players have lost/time is up the game goes to the next round.
The ploblem occurs when both players have lost. The method NextRound in the SetTime method,
runs twice. 
Here is the code:

```
void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SetTime(e.ProgressPercentage);
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    int tick = ProgLib.maxTime * 10;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            Thread.Sleep(tick);
            worker.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }
}

private void SetTime(double k)
{
    this.time.Bar1.Value = k;
    this.time.Bar2.Value = k;

    if (k >= 100 || (Gallery1.hasLost() && Gallery2.hasLost()) || ((Gallery1.isWinner() || Gallery2.isWinner())))
    {
        if (bw == null)
            return;
        bw.CancelAsync();
        bw.Dispose();
        bw = null;

        saveData();
        ProgLib.isAnyoneWinner(Gallery1.isWinner(), Gallery2.isWinner());
        if (ProgLib.gameHasended())
        {
            gameHasEnded();

        }
        else
        {
            next_round();
        }
    }
}

private void next_round()
{
    Thread nextRoundThread = new Thread((Object Send) =>
    {
        MainThread.Send((Object send) =>
        {
            Gallery1.hidePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Gallery2.hidePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            ProgLib.nextLetter();//goes to next letter
            LetterToPlay1.setLetter(ProgLib.getArrabicLetter(ProgLib.getCurentLetter()));//sets the next letter
            LetterToPlay2.setLetter(ProgLib.getArrabicLetter(ProgLib.getCurentLetter()));

        }, null);

        Thread SoundThread = new Thread((Object send) =>
        {
            //Here Must Delay enought so the animation stops the hear the bell and the the letter, and then the game starts
            Thread.Sleep(1800);
            ProgLib.playOtherSound(ProgLib.Sounds.Chimes);//Bell Sound
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            //ProgLib.PlayLetterSound(ProgLib.getCurentLetter());//Letter Sound
            ProgLib.playOtherSound(ProgLib.Sounds.Cat_Yawn);//TestOnly
        });
        SoundThread.IsBackground = true;
        SoundThread.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        MainThread.Send((Object send) =>
        {
            Gallery1.refresh();//galleries refresh so that the magician hides.
            Gallery2.refresh();//
            Gallery1.hidePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;//hide the Big Magician of  mistakes
            Gallery2.hidePanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }, null);

    });
    nextRoundThread.IsBackground = true;
    nextRoundThread.Start();

    bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this only happens when both players have lost? Or does it happen in other situations as well?

Comment: I'm sure it happens when both players have lost. I have tested many times. the save file it has double entries and the audio file plays twice. in any other situation there is one antry and and the audio plays once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a threading race in your code.  Your worker will call ReportProgress() and immediately iterate the loop.  Racing past the CancellationPending property check and falling asleep again.

Your SetTime() method runs *later*.  And calls CancelAsync() but that doesn't have any effect at all since the worker is sleeping.  Not until it wakes up again, calls ReportProgress() again, iterates the loop and *then* sees CancellationPending set to true.

Your SetTime() method will be called again, even though you've already ended the game.

Threading is rife with problems like this.  A band-aid is to check for CancellationPending after the Sleep() call.  Which works 99.999% of the time.  Getting to 100% requires a pretty drastic rewrite that uses proper locking.

Comment: Ok You are awsome!!!! I did the changes and now works fine!!!! Thanks you so much! I was trying to fix this problem for days.  the truth is a am very new and also very bad at Threading....